# How to remove Authorization header on redirect on any Flutter/Dart http client

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

I'm currently working on a project which like a lot of other projects works with s3 storage. In this case the storage is linked via the back-end.

The situation is like this, I can get the 'attachment' via an URL, lets say `example.com/api/attachments/{uuid}`. If the user is authorized (via the header `Authorization`) it should return a `302` statuscode and redirect to the s3 url. The problem is that after the redirect the `Authorization` header persists and the http client return a `400` response and it's because of the persisting `Authorization` header. Is there any way I can remove the `Authorization` header after redirect without catching the first request and firing a new one?

My http client code currently looks like this:

```dart
  @override
  Future get({
    String url,
    Map<String, dynamic> data,
    Map<String, String> parameters,
  }) async {
    await _refreshClient();
    try {
      final response = await dio.get(
        url,
        data: json.encode(data),
        queryParameters: parameters,
      );
      return response.data;
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      throw ServerException(
        statusCode: e.response.statusCode,
        message: e.response.statusMessage,
      );
    }
  }

  Future<void> _refreshClient() async {
    final token = await auth.token;
    dio.options.baseUrl = config.baseUrl;
    dio.options.headers.addAll({
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
    });
    dio.options.contentType = 'application/json';
  }
```

Comment: I have the exact same problem. This is actually a concerning security issue - I don't want headers intended for my service sent to a 3rd party redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news! This has been fixed recently with Dart 2.16 / Flutter v2.10!

Related bugs in dart issue tracker:

- https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/47246
- https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/45410

Official announcement:
https://medium.com/dartlang/dart-2-16-improved-tooling-and-platform-handling-dd87abd6bad1

**TLDR: upgrade to Flutter v2.10!**

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Dio docs, it seems like this is intentional behaviour.

> All headers added to the request will be added to the redirection request(s). However, any body send with the request will not be part of the redirection request(s).

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/HttpClientRequest/followRedirects.html

However, I understand (and agree!) that this is generally undesirable behaviour. My solution is to manually follow the redirects myself, which is not very nice but works in a pinch.

```
    Response<String> response;
    try {
      response = await dio.get(
        url,
        options: Options(
          // Your headers here, which might be your auth headers
          headers: ...,
          // This is the key - avoid following redirects automatically and handle it ourselves
          followRedirects: false,
        ),
      );
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      final initialResponse = e.response;

      // You can modify this to understand other kinds of redirects like 301 or 307
      if (initialResponse != null && initialResponse.statusCode == 302) {
        response = await dio.get(
          initialResponse.headers.value("location")!, // We must get a location header if we got a redirect
          ),
        );
      } else {
        // Rethrow here in all other cases
        throw e;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah this is currently how I’ve solved it as well.. not really slick but it does the job